# SQL insert into statement leads to weird (cartesian product) result

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am using PostgreSQL 11 and PostGIS 2.5.1 and trying to create a new column in an existing table with a specific value

the sample table is as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (id integer, geom GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO test (id, geom)
VALUES 
(1, ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-71.00 42.00)')),
(2, ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(52.00 52.00)'));
```

If I create a new column and execute an insert into statement the result is like a cartesian product

```
ALTER Table test
ADD wkt_text TEXT;


INSERT INTO test (wkt_text)
SELECT st_astext(a.geom)::text FROM test a, test b
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

The result looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
 id |                        geom                        |   wkt_text    
----+----------------------------------------------------+---------------
  1 | 0101000020E61000000000000000C051C00000000000004540 | 
  2 | 0101000020E61000000000000000004A400000000000004A40 | 
    |                                                    | POINT(-71 42)
    |                                                    | POINT(52 52)
```

Any reason why this is happening? Insert into is working with no problems on tables with empty columns. As soon there is a column filled with a values, the result is is as described.

I get a correct result with following query but I want to understand why.

```
WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT id, st_astext(geom)::text AS wkt_text
    FROM test 
)
UPDATE test
SET wkt_text=subquery.wkt_text
FROM subquery
WHERE test.id = subquery.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT` inserts new *rows* into the table.  Columns not specified in the `INSERT` are given `NULL` values (or specified defaults).

`UPDATE` updates columns in *existing* rows.  That appears to be the logic that you want and you have the correct statement for it.